# VBA - While - IF - Else with several statements

Tags: vba, excel

i'm pretty new at VBA and my little knowledge come from google research.
I have spent all day trying to solve that issue and was hoping for some help here as it it probably something simple

What I try to do is to convert my Columns to Numbers, and then copy the columns in which my value is not 0.
I'm sorry my code is pretty big and ugly I made the problematic part inside the **

[edit] Excuse me I was a bit in a rush, the main problem is that after

If valCell.value = 0 Then
Else: blabla
End if

The code jumps directly to End IF.
No I realize that maybe I should put the End IF before the Else ?
[/edit]

Thanks alot in advance!

```
Sub filter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Windows("file1.csv").Activate
    Range("B:B,C:C,E:E,F:F,G:G,I:I,J:J,K:K,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("file2.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("J2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-6],'Buffer Page'!C[-9],1,FALSE),""0"")"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J2:J500")
    Range("J2:J500").Select
        Range("K2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'Buffer Page'!C[-10],1,FALSE),""0"")"
    Range("K2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K2:K500")
    Range("K2:K110").Select

Range("J2:K500").Select
   ' Convertion to Numbers
For Each xCell In Selection
xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
Next xCell

Dim NumeroLigne As Integer

Sheets("2ndBuffer").Select

    FinLigne = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1  ' Variable 1
    NumeroLigne = 2 'Variable 2
    Set valCell = Range("J" & NumeroLigne)

   Sheets("2ndBuffer").Select
   While NumeroLigne < FinLigne
        Sheets("2ndBuffer").Range("J" & NumeroLigne).Select

        **If valCell.Value = 0 Then

        Else: Range("A" & NumeroLigne, "I" & NumeroLigne).Select     
       Range("D" & NumeroLigne) Then
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("MNAs").Select
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
       Sheets("2ndBuffer").Select**

       End If


       NumeroLigne = NumeroLigne + 1

       Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to clarify your issue. What exact problem did you faced with?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question. I'm very exctited about this website, hopefuly one day i will be able to help people too :)

Comment: @MaximePetit What is valCell.Value when you execute that IF statement?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld valCell.value  is set earlier as follows : Set valCell = Range("J" & NumeroLigne). It refers to the Column + Line I'm working on. It is probably useless though, I was trying alot of different things to sort my issues

Comment: @MaximePetit In order to debug this, you need to set  break points and examine the contents of the variables as you go throught the code.  You may think that you have done what you have written, but you will probably find that you have not.  Look closely at the contents and address of valCell

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have tried to do that and identified that the main problem was the code jumping directly from  Then to End IF. I have tried all day to change bits of code everywhere but it just won't work

Comment: @RonRosenfeld valCell is set as a range, do you imply that I cannot write valCell.value ?

Comment: What confuses me - you have `If valCell.Value = 0 Then` , and then nothing.  Then it jumps to an `Else` block.  Why not scrap both, and put everything between `Range("A" & NumeroLigne, "I" & NumeroLigne).Select` and `Sheets("2ndBuffer").Select**` in this If statement: `If valCell <> 0 Then`.  Also, turn back on screen updating to debug, and instead of running the code, use F8 to step through it line by line, and hover the mouse over variables to check their current value

Comment: Yeah I tried that, in such case everything under `Range("A" & NumeroLigne, "I" & NumeroLigne).Select and Sheets("2ndBuffer").Select` is still happening no matter if valCell = 0 or not. About `f valCell.Value = 0 Then` my idea what to have Nothing happening if valCell = 0 (going down to end if), and apply my code if it is not = 0. Finally, I have been using F8, I just wanted to show all the code and highlight the one I have troubles with.

Comment: @MaximePetit  You can certainly write valCell.value.  But you need to know exactly what that value is when you are running your code.  Not that you, at some point in the code, set it to a value; but what that value actually is.  Does it ever contain anything other than the value that is in J2?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Well my idea what to change the value after each loop. First J2, then J3, J4... And if valCell.value is not equal to 0 then copy A4:I4 to MNAs sheet. I'm sorry I cannot make tests until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that valCell never changes once you originally set it to J2.  Here is your code, vastly simplified to show only this point.  If you run the code, you will see that valCell **always** points to J2.

Option Explicit

```
Sub Simple()
    Dim valCell As Range
    Dim xCell As Range
    Dim FinLigne As Long
    Dim NmeroLigne As Long

Range("J2:K10").Select
   ' Convertion to Numbers
For Each xCell In Selection
xCell.Value = CDec(xCell.Value)
Next xCell

Dim NumeroLigne As Integer

    FinLigne = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1  ' Variable 1
    NumeroLigne = 2 'Variable 2

    Set valCell = Range("J" & NumeroLigne)

While NumeroLigne < FinLigne
    If valCell.Value = 0 Then

        Debug.Print valCell.Address

    End If
       NumeroLigne = NumeroLigne + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

**If you want valCell to change, you need to set it INSIDE the While ... Wend loop.**  It only takes the value of NumeroLigne at the time it is set.  Unless you set it again, it will remain pointing to the original.

Comment: Thanks alot Ron! I think that I just started to go crazy after fixing different issues and each time facing new ones, or not dealing with them and trying alternative. All that blurred my thinking. I will try that tomorrow and keep you updated :) PS: I didn't know about that Debug.Print, it will definitively help me in the future